# C++ Visual Studio succesful compiling but exe not found in debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

My project compiles and run well in release.

But when I set to debug, it only compiles, but it does not run. The .exe disappears when I try to run it and it throws me an error " xxx.exe not found"

The weirdest thing is that when I remove some specific function/method calls on my code, it runs.

Comment: I just tried with Code::Blocks it runs well, it's really weird. I repaired my visual studio installation but still the same ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, it was my antivirus (AVAST), who was deleting my .exe without even noticing me.

(I'am answering my own question so maybe it can help other people)

Comment: A few weeks ago I have had the same happen to me. The heuristic scan had way too many false positives in c++ code that I had on my PC.